# django rest framework, создание нового пользователя и аутентификация существующего

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

Идентификатором моих юзеров будет номер телефона, а аутентификация будет осуществляться с помощью токенов. Исходя из этого есть несколько вопросов:
Надо ли мне расширять модель user (BaseAbstractUser и тд)?
Нужно ли мне хранить токен юзера в базе?
Как описать процесс аутентификации?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно сделать, например, так:

your_users_app/models.py:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from phonenumber_field.modelfields import PhoneNumberField
# про PhoneNumberField узнать подробнее можно здесь - https://github.com/daviddrysdale/python-phonenumbers
# его использование вовсе не обязательно, но я делал именно так 
from django.utils.encoding import python_2_unicode_compatible

    @python_2_unicode_compatible
    class User(AbstractUser):
        id = PhoneNumberField()

        def __str__(self):
            return self.username
```

your_users_app/serializers.py:

```
from rest_framework import serializers

from .models import User


class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'first_name', 'last_name',)
        read_only_fields = ('username', )


class CreateUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = User.objects.create_user(**validated_data)
        return user

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'password', 'auth_token')
        read_only_fields = ('auth_token',)
        extra_kwargs = {'password': {'write_only': True}}
```

your_users_app/views.py:

```
from rest_framework import viewsets, mixins
from rest_framework.permissions import AllowAny

from .models import User
from .permissions import IsUserOrReadOnly
from .serializers import CreateUserSerializer, UserSerializer


class UserViewSet(mixins.CreateModelMixin,
                  mixins.RetrieveModelMixin,
                  mixins.UpdateModelMixin,
                  viewsets.GenericViewSet):

    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsUserOrReadOnly,)

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.serializer_class = CreateUserSerializer
        self.permission_classes = (AllowAny,)
        return super(UserViewSet, self).create(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

your_users_app/permissions.py:

```
from rest_framework import permissions


class IsUserOrReadOnly(permissions.BasePermission):


    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):

        if request.method in permissions.SAFE_METHODS:
            return True

        return obj == request.user
```

в Ваш основной `urls.py` добавьте следующее:

```
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.views.generic.base import RedirectView
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter
from your_users_app.views import UserViewSet


router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'users', UserViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    ...
    url(r'^api/v1/', include('authentication.urls')),
    url(r'^api/v1/', include(router.urls)),
    ...
    # про 'api-root' в качестве роутера по дефолту можно почитать тут                                 
    # http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/#defaultrouter
    url(r'^$', RedirectView.as_view(url=reverse_lazy('api-root'), permanent=False)),
    ...
]
```

Не знаю, правильно ли на [stackoverflow.com](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/) давать развёрнутые ответы, но меня когда-то тоже мучил аналогичный вопрос, а так же то, как же правильно организовать структуру. Этот вариант кажется вполне себе неплохим. Пусть поправят те, кто разбираются лучше.